# using GetSubwebsForCurrentUser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to adapt the example on MSDN [Enumerate Sites](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms462161.aspx) to only display sites the user has access to. Given the example below, would this be the proper way?

```
        string webUrl = "http://siteurl";

        using (SPWeb oWebsite = new SPSite(webUrl).OpenWeb())
        {
            oWebsite.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser();
            SPWebCollection collWebsite = oWebsite.Webs;

            foreach (SPWeb subSite in collWebsite)
            {
                Label1.Text += SPEncode.HtmlEncode(subSite.Title) + "<BR>";
                subSite.Close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

[SPWeb.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getsubwebsforcurrentuser.aspx)  will provide you list of all webs directly under the Web which is calling the method.But if we have any sub site inside of sub site , then this will not provide that. For those scenarios you  will have to either loop through or call **GetSubwebsForCurrentUser** recursively for each sub web returned.

Another better approach will be to use **KeywordQuery**.

```
                    KeywordQuery query = new KeywordQuery(site);
                    query.QueryText = string.Format("Path:{0} AND ContentClass:STS_Web", site.Url);
                    query.RowLimit = 500;//max row limit is 500 for KeywordQuery
                    query.ResultsProvider = SearchProvider.Default;
                    query.EnableStemming = true;
                    query.TrimDuplicates = false;
                    query.AuthenticationType = QueryAuthenticationType.PluggableAuthenticatedQuery;
                    query.KeywordInclusion = KeywordInclusion.AllKeywords;
                    SearchExecutor executor = new SearchExecutor();
                    ResultTableCollection resultTableCollection = executor.ExecuteQuery(query);
                    var resultTables = resultTableCollection.Filter("TableType", KnownTableTypes.RelevantResults);
                    var resultTable = resultTables.FirstOrDefault();
```

This will leverage 2013 Search APIs and return you all subsites under that site which user has access to.

Answer (score 0):

Close, except that you are orphaning an SPSite object each time this runs as both the SPSite object and the SPWeb objects need to be disposed of.  Also, you are calling .Close() on the subsite in the inner loop but that should be a .Dispose().  something like this:

```
   string webUrl = "http://siteurl";

   using (SPSite site = new SPSite(webUrl)) {
        using (SPWeb oWebsite = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            SPWebCollection collWebsite = oWebsite.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser();

            foreach (SPWeb subSite in collWebsite)
            {
                Label1.Text += SPEncode.HtmlEncode(subSite.Title) + "<BR />";
                subSite.Dispose();
            }
        }
   }
```

When in doubt, refer to the [Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973248%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for disposing of SharePoint objects

Comment: Does this pull in sub site collections from the root SP online url? Using this code I'm getting an empty list for collWebsite even though I'm logged on/authenticated.