# Do I need to dispose spweb here

Tags: office-365

Do i need to dispose anything in this code,

```
  SPWebCollection webs = SPContext.Current.Web.GetSubwebsForCurrentUser();

            if (webs.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (SPWeb web in webs)
                { 

                }
            }
```

for each web i will get its properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not one hundred percent sure, but I would say Yes you should.

Most information tells you that, like [using GetSubwebsForCurrentUser](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/67730/using-getsubwebsforcurrentuser).

The only difference is that you are calling the method from SPContext, but since you are calling a method in the context web I'm quite sure that new web objects will be created for your enumerator!

To be completely sure you could use ILSpy or similar on the method to see how it works, but I'm quite confident this is what happens and that you therefore need to dispose

Comment: Agree with you..

Comment: Robert, suppose there is something like SPWeb=SPContext.Current.Web, we know we should not dispose this, however, if we put this in an USING block, then will it throw error?

Comment: You should not put SPWeb=SPContext.Current.Web in a using. Though, you can call SPContext.Current.Web inside of the using if needed